# Gracefully terminate a Boost Asio based Windows console application

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, windows-console, taskkill

I am working on a boost.asio based HTTP server. It is supposed to be stopped externally. We use asio signal handling, and it works well for ctrl-c, but does not handle WM_CLOSE, so there is no straightforward way to gracefully close the application externally, e.g. via taskkill. Terminating the process forcibly is not an option. Is there a known approach to this?

Comment: Could you try to start your app with `start "MyApp" myapp.exe` and then use `taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq MyApp*"` to send an event to your app that can be handled with a handler set by `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` (see answer below) ? That way you're killing the containing `cmd.exe` which then sends a `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT` (IIRC) to your app.

Comment: Thank you! That's very useful too. Is there a straightforward way to make the console hidden (not using third party utilities)? If no, I guess I can write up a trivial launcher, creating a new hidden console for my process.

Comment: I was hoping MSVC would map CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT to some signal, so asio can catch it, but apparently this does not happen. Tried  SIGINT, SIGTERM, SIGBREAK, SIGABRT, SIGABRT_COMPAT. Any idea?

Comment: @DmitryShubin, MSVC maps Ctrl+C to `SIGINT`, and all other events are mapped to `SIGBREAK`. I just tested with a simple `SIGBREAK` handler installed via `signal`. This definitely works to handle `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`. The issue is that taskkill.exe will only send `WM_CLOSE` to the effective owner of the console, determined from enumerating windows and calling `GetWindowsThreadProcessId`. Usually this is the process that allocated the console, if it's still running. But closing the console will also kill every process that's attached to it; they get 5 seconds to exit cleanly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Just use any IPC method you would "normally" use

1. Write a simple process control utility that uses e.g. [`named_condition`](http://tinyurl.com/ln8bsyu) to signal your asio process to shutdown.

   <sub>Note that `named_codition` is somewhat equivalent to a Win32 Named Event in case you think that simpler for this inherently platform specific piece of code</sub>
2. Consider making a [**Windows Service (NTService)**](http://tinyurl.com/oe48lzv), as it looks like this is what you want
3. As a long shot, try to create a toplevel window from your process; Either **[`AllocConsole`](http://tinyurl.com/kkt4xgy)** or **[`CreateWindow`](http://tinyurl.com/d8kd2lc)** could help. However, you end up with more platform specific stuff

---

***Original answer***, dealing with how to listen for console close events:

This is really not related to using Boost Asio. Of course, on POSIX platforms you could use `boost::asio::signal_set` to handle the SIG_INT and SIG_TERM signals.

However, you're on windows, and there is no portable way to detect console close event.

You should write a console handler routine that detects CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT (and CTRL_C_EVENT, if desired), and use SetConsoleCtrlHandler to add the handler routine to your process.

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

BOOL CtrlHandler( DWORD fdwCtrlType ) 
{ 
  switch( fdwCtrlType ) 
  { 
    // Handle the CTRL-C signal. 
    case CTRL_C_EVENT: 
      printf( "Ctrl-C event\n\n" );
      Beep( 750, 300 ); 
      return( TRUE );

    // CTRL-CLOSE: confirm that the user wants to exit. 
    case CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT: 
      Beep( 600, 200 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Close event\n\n" );
      return( TRUE ); 

    // Pass other signals to the next handler. 
    case CTRL_BREAK_EVENT: 
      Beep( 900, 200 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Break event\n\n" );
      return FALSE; 

    case CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT: 
      Beep( 1000, 200 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Logoff event\n\n" );
      return FALSE; 

    case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT: 
      Beep( 750, 500 ); 
      printf( "Ctrl-Shutdown event\n\n" );
      return FALSE; 

    default: 
      return FALSE; 
  } 
} 

int main( void ) 
{ 
  if( SetConsoleCtrlHandler( (PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE ) ) 
  { 
    printf( "\nThe Control Handler is installed.\n" ); 
    printf( "\n -- Now try pressing Ctrl+C or Ctrl+Break, or" ); 
    printf( "\n    try logging off or closing the console...\n" ); 
    printf( "\n(...waiting in a loop for events...)\n\n" ); 

    while( 1 ){ } 
  } 
  else 
  {
    printf( "\nERROR: Could not set control handler"); 
    return 1;
  }
return 0;
}
```

To coordinate with Boost Asio, you could have the handler stop the (global) io_service object and perhaps set some flag for running actions. Finally, you may have to *cancel* any async operations in flight (e.g. `deadline_timer`s).

Once you did that, it should be pretty clean.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only works if I press ctrl-c or ctrl-break, but not if I kill it from outside. Specifically, calling taskkill gives this:
'ERROR: The process "term_test.exe" with PID 11656 could not be terminated.'
'Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).'

Comment: Ok, thank you for your suggestions. I agree Windows Service is the proper way to go, but for some reasons our client prefers a console. Will likely go with a window solution. Can you please update your initial reply so it matches the question more closely, and I can accept it?

Comment: @DmitryShubin, there's no reliable way to signal an individual console application in general. But if you know it was started as a process group leader, then you can attach to its console and send Ctrl+Break (i.e. C `SIGBREAK`) to the whole group. If it's not a group leader, that will end up sending Ctrl+Break to every process attached to the console. Also, only one process is the effective owner of the console, to kill without `/F` via `WM_CLOSE`. However, that will also kill all attached processes, since Ctrl+Close event allows 5 seconds to exit cleanly before terminating.

Comment: The comment "CTRL-CLOSE: confirm that the user wants to exit" is no longer valid since Vista. Console applications cannot prevent the console from closing. They have 5 seconds to exit gracefully. Then csrss.exe (which injects the control thread on behalf of conhost.exe) will forcibly kill them via `TerminateProcess`, with the exit code `STATUS_CONTROL_C_EXIT`. The handler should do any required cleanup and call `exit` with a better status code if it exited cleanly.