# Gracefully shut-down command-line application on console window closure (on windows)

Tags: c++, c, windows, console-application

I have a small(ish) command-line application that talks to some custom hardware.

Right now, you run the executable, and it pops up a console window, and does it's thing. I'm handling `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` so if you hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> *in* the console window, it shuts down gracefully, and releases the custom hardware.

However, if kill the application by simply closing the console window (click the "x" in the corner), it seems to basically be immediately killed, with no time to do *any* cleanup.

I'd like to be able to do my shutdown procedures if the console is closed. I've not had much luck trying to find out what, exactly, is even happening to my process when it's console is closed.

Comment: Your application is either written in C, or written in C++. Which is it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - It's C++, but I'd accept either c or c++ answers. I'd prefer C++, but I don't have issues calling C APIs.

Comment: Being that they are two different languages, we would prefer you focus on one at a time (and only tag one at a time unless the question is specifically about the differences/similarities between them).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - This question is basically a "where's the right API" thing, and I don't really care whether the answer is c or c++. Anyways, the dupe answers my question, so I guess it's irrelevant.

Comment: We care, as I have stated.

Answer (score 0):

And as soon as I ask the question, I find [Gracefully terminate a Boost Asio based Windows console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404907/gracefully-terminate-a-boost-asio-based-windows-console-application), which exactly answers it (I'm even using boost-asio!).